# <AST>:1:33: unexpected AST node error for a HQL insert

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

This is my entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courier_upload_queue")
public class CourierUploadQueue  {

    private int id;
    private String crp_code;
    private Status status;
    private Date time_created;
    private Date last_update;
    private String courier_name;
    private Integer retry_count;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name= "status", nullable= false)
    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name= "crp_code", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getCrp_code() {
        return crp_code;
    }

    public void setCrp_code(String crp_code) {
        this.crp_code = crp_code;
    }

    @Column(name="time_created", nullable = false)
    public Date getTime_created() {
        return time_created;
    }

    public void setTime_created(Date time_created) {
        this.time_created = time_created;
    }

    @Column(name="last_update", nullable = false)
    public Date getLast_update() {
        return last_update;
    }

    public void setLast_update(Date last_update) {
        this.last_update = last_update;
    }


    @Column(name="courier_name", nullable = false)
    public String getCourier_name() {
        return courier_name;
    }

    public void setCourier_name(String courier_name) {
        this.courier_name = courier_name;
    }

    @Column(name="retry_count", nullable = false)
    public Integer getRetry_count() {
        return retry_count;
    }

    public void setRetry_count(Integer retry_count) {
        this.retry_count = retry_count;
    }

}
```

and this is my DaoImpl

```
@Override
public void insertToCourierUploadQueue(String crp_code, String courier_name)
{
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("insert into CourierUploadQueue (:crp_code, 'PENDING', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() , :courier_name, 0 )");
    query.setParameter("crp_code", crp_code);
    query.setParameter("courier_name", courier_name.toLowerCase());
    query.executeUpdate();  
}
```

I've created the corresponding table in my database.

I'm getting the error message:

> could not resolve property: : of: com.pooja.entity.CourierUploadQueue

Can you guys please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: its throwing for which property ?

Comment: can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: Hope this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572256/java-hibernate-insertion

Comment: This too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bohuslav was right. INSERT INTO ... VALUES is not supported in HQL.

Instead, I did this :

```
public void insertToCourierUploadQueue(String crp_code, String courier_name){Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        CourierUploadQueue courierUploadQueue = new CourierUploadQueue();
        courierUploadQueue.setCrp_code(crp_code);
        courierUploadQueue.setCourier_name(courier_name);
        courierUploadQueue.setLast_update(new Date());
        courierUploadQueue.setTime_created(new Date());
        courierUploadQueue.setRetry_count(0);
        courierUploadQueue.setStatus(CourierUploadQueueStatus.Status.PENDING);
        session1.save(courierUploadQueue);
        session1.close();}
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES` is not supported in HQL, hence the error. Only `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. See the [*DML-style operations*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/batch-direct.html) section of the documentation for details:

> The pseudo-syntax for INSERT statements is: `INSERT INTO EntityName properties_list select_statement`. Some points to note:
>
> Only the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` form is supported; not the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` form.

If you want to perform `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` you should probably use SQL and `session.createNativeQuery()` instead.